# Starting Service Applications on SharePoint2010

Tags: excel-services

I have noted that some of the service applications on my central admin are in  stopped status, so i want to start them and don't no how to start them as I won't see any start option available on that service application.

Note: I am trying to start Service Application not Services on Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provision/unprovision Service Applications via PowerShell. First get a list of service applications:

```
Get-SPServiceApplication | select displayname,id,status
```

Then obtain a reference to the disabled Service Application by copying its GUID and feeding it to this command:

```
$sa = Get-SPServiceApplication [GUID]
```

Finally, provision (start) the service application:

```
$sa.Provision()
```

Comment: Thank you Thomas.  but do we have any way to do it through Central Admin ?

Comment: There is no way to do it in the user interface unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

in Central Administration, the Services on Server lists your application services, so if you have already provisioned them and they are stopped, this is where you start them (click start)

[image: Example Image of services on server]

Additionally, if the services are provisioned, and WONT start, check the server event logs (if nothing here, then go to ULS), you probably have an issue to deal with in regards to the AppPool (usually account related, i.e. locked or wrong password).